# Undefined reference to v8 when linking c++ node addon using gyp

Tags: c++, node.js, opencv, v8

I'm trying to build a node addon using the opencv library. I'm compiling it using node-gyp.
I've achieved to link opencv using the `binding.gyp` config file, but I have some issues with the v8 library.

Here is my binding.gyp file:

```
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "test",
            "sources": [ "src/native/test.cpp" ],
            "include_dirs": [
                "/usr/local/include/opencv4",
                "/usr/local/include/node",
                "/usr/include"
            ],
            "library_dirs": [ "/usr/local/lib", "/usr/lib" ],
            "libraries": [
                "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so",
                "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so",
                "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so",
                "/usr/lib/libv8.so"
            ],
            "ldflags": [ "-Wl,-z,defs" ],
            "link_settings": {
                "libraries": [
                    "-lopencv_core",
                    "-lopencv_videoio",
                    "-lopencv_highgui",
                    "-lv8",
                    "-lpthread"
                 ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Without linking opencv, I haven't any problem to build and run my addon, but as soon as I link opencv, the build failed because of v8:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x1f9): undefined reference to `v8::V8::ToLocalEmpty()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to `v8::V8::FromJustIsNothing()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `v8::V8::ToLocalEmpty()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x229): undefined reference to `v8::V8::ToLocalEmpty()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to `v8::V8::FromJustIsNothing()'
... and so on
```

As you can see in the binding.gyp file, I've tried to link the corresponding libraries and include for v8, but it doesn't make it.

I'm pretty sure it's a problem or a conflict with the configuration itself, because without linking opencv, the build works great and I've no problems to use the addon in a nodeJS file.

My c++ file is very simple, it's as simple as possible since I just want it to build and link libraries correctly:

```
#include <opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv4/opencv2/highgui.hpp>

#include <node/v8.h>
#include <node/node.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

void capture(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args)
{
    v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::GetCurrent();
    v8::HandleScope scope(isolate);

    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
}

void Initialize(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "capture", capture);
}

NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize)
```

If you have any ideas about this build error, and why v8 isn't linking correctly when linking opencv, I would appreciate any help,

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't node-gyp automatically add the node libraries and include dirs?

Comment: For node.h and v8 yes it does, but when I link opencv in the binding.gyp, node-hyp can't find anymore v8

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't you link OpenCV statically, It licensed under Apache license. The Apache License does not place any restrictions on linking

```
rm -rf 3rdparty/opencv
mkdir -p 3rdparty/opencv
rm -rf tmp
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
rm -rf opencv-master
rm -rf opencv_contrib-master
git clone --branch 3.4 --depth 1 https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git opencv-master
git clone --branch 3.4 --depth 1 https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git opencv_contrib-master
mkdir build
cd build
cmake \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$(pwd)/../../3rdparty/opencv\@3.4" \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
    -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=YES \
    -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-master/modules \
    ../opencv-master
cmake --build .
make install
```

I created a simple script which will compile OpenCV 3.4 with [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) (SIFT, SURF available) for statically linking with [Native Abstractions for Node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/nan).

```
{
    "targets": [
    {
        "target_name": "addon",
        "cflags": [
            "-std=c++11",
            "-stdlib=libc++"
        ],
        "cflags_cc!": [
            "-fno-rtti",
            "-fno-exceptions"
        ],
        "xcode_settings": {
            "GCC_ENABLE_CPP_RTTI": "YES",
            "GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS": "YES",
        },
        "include_dirs": [
            "../../3rdparty/opencv/@3.4/include",
            "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"
        ],
        'libraries': [
            "<!@(node utils/find-libs.js)",
            "-framework OpenCL"
        ],
        "sources": [
            "./src/main.cc",
            "./src/lib/MainAddon.cc"
        ],
    }
  ]
}
```

The full source code is large enough so It published in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/node-gyp-opencv)